# Facebook Community

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

how to find a facebook url is community url or profile url using facebook API

For example 
http://www.facebook.com/adelphi.panthers

http://www.facebook.com/BryantAthletics

Which is profile url and which is community url, how to find?

Comment: By community are you referring to a Facebook group or page..?

Comment: No i want to identify  **BryantAthletics** or **adelphi.panthers** community or group profile

Comment: Okay.. But I guess FB now calls a community as a page. Take a look at - 
[Graph API > Facebook Objects](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

Comment: Ok, then how can i identify it is page or profile

Comment: Easy.. I'm posting my way of doing it...

Comment: Do you mind sharing a bit more details on what you are trying to achieve here..? The only application I can think of that could use such a function is harvesting of Facebook profile/group links ...

Comment: @KentPawar i got worked it from your answer early.., but i forget to accept it Thanks

Comment: that's cool.. Another question answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as @Lix has suggested you could do something like this:

**Request:** https://graph.facebook.com/BryantAthletics?fields=gender

**HTTP Response:** 400 Bad Request

**JSON Response:**

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Unknown fields: gender.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

This tells us its NOT a User object. But then it could be a group or a page.. So you need to make another request using an attribute that is unique either to a group or page. Depending on how you make the request, you could decide to handle the result accordingly.

Consider,

**Request:** https://graph.facebook.com/adelphi.panthers?fields=gender

**HTTP Response:** 200 OK

**JSON Response:**

```
{
   "gender": "female",
   "id": "1360823630"
}
```

Now this tells us that the gender attribute exist within this Facebook object and so  it is definitely a user.

I'm assuming you are using JQuery to capture and parse the response. Then you would check for the error attribute in the JSON variable to determine the object type.

Comment: @Elby i take it that this answered your question. Could you mark the question as answered/Closed. thanks!
Unless you have found a better way of doing it and would like to share that here...

Answer (score 2):

> The links you provided were for a Facebook user and for a Facebook page. I'm going to assume that by "community url" you mean Facebook page...

Ok, so I think it will be pretty simple to detect what is a Facebook Page and what is a User according to the username (or ID).

All you would have to do (in these cases), is query the Graph API with the username -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/adelphi.panthers

{
  "id": "1360823630", 
  "name": "Adelphi Panthers", 
  "first_name": "Adelphi", 
  "last_name": "Panthers", 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/adelphi.panthers", 
  "username": "adelphi.panthers", 
  "gender": "female", 
  "locale": "en_US", 
  "updated_time": "2012-10-09T12:51:38+0000"
}
```

As you can see, this call to the API returned a gender parameter. Pages can not have genders so we can assume this is a Facebook User.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/BryantAthletics

{
  "name": "Bryant Athletics", 
  "is_published": true, 
  "website": "bryantbulldogs.com", 
  "username": "BryantAthletics", 
  ...
  "category": "School sports team", 
  ...
}
```

You can see here that much much more information is being returned to us. I think the Category parameter is a good indication that this specific username is related to a page. Users can not choose a category for themselves...

Comment: Ok thanks for your replay, but any other unique method for finding this? i think user type like that?

Comment: What user types are there? What would you look for?

Comment: Lix,  identify **BryantAthletics** or **adelphi.panthers** community or group profile

Comment: @elb - you are inventing terms that Facebook doesn't use. Please explain what you are looking for. There is no such thing as a  community profile...

Comment: @Lix Yup Elby was referring to a Page.
[Community Pages](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=168393039888715)

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are working with java then don't pass any parameter of gender type.
it will automatically accept.
I had the same problem but now its resolved. 

My working code is: 

User user = client.fetchObject("username", User.class);
        System.out.println("Gender: " + user.getGender());
```